# Text overlay over video stream when saving to file system

Tags: python, video, raspicam, c

I'am using raspberry pi zero as controller which communicate over UART with external board with five sensors. What I need is a way to save video stream from raspicam to filesystem with embedded text (text overlay). Anyone know some library or project to do that?

Comment: Is the [text annotation system](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#overlaying-text-on-the-output) not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
convert -pointsize 28 -fill yellow -draw 'text 270,460 "How I can use a searchengine to find answers." ' SearchEnginee.jpg SearchEnginee2.jpg
```

This will create SearchEnginee2.jpg with a text overlay.

Comment: HI, is possible to overlay text over video stream (h264)? I know that raspivid support text overlay but only at fixed position..